# How can I get on the 'tourist trail'?

Tags: idioms, english-comparison, translation

In English we have an idiom - the tourist trail - to talk about the popular route of tourist through a place. My translation is strada di turismo but I am sure that this is not right.

Can some kind soul help me with this, please, as I am sure that Italians have a lot to say about tourists.

Comment: Bear in mind this idiom doesn't exist in Italian for a reason: often it's so full of places to go to that there can't be a "path" crossing them all.

Comment: It doesn't mean an actual path but more like the places that tourists commonly visit eg "Venice is on the tourist trail in Italy."

Comment: You might want to consider _mete turistiche_ as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this idiom does not get a straightforward translation in Italian.

I would express it as *percorso turistico*.

As a side note, if you want to talk about some very popular route people use (also in a metaphorical sense, so not necessarily a real path, but maybe a path in life, habits ...), you can say *percorso battuto/strada battuta*, where the adjective means "something which many people use, go through, wlak through".

Comment: Thanks, Martina. A simple, easily understood answer to my question.

Answer (score 6):

[Itinerario turistico](http://it.glosbe.com/en/it/touristic%20route)  is a common and useful expression:

> - An established or selected course for travel consisting, typically, of secondary roads with significant scenic, cultural, historic, geological or natural features and including vistas, rest areas, and interpretive sites matching the scenic characteristics of the course.

[Sei itinerari turistici a piedi a Roma](http://www.roma2000.it/visite.html)

> - le sei proposte di itinerario che si presentano non hanno certo l'ambizione di esaurire la conoscenza dei luoghi che si visitano, ma di trasmettere al turista, spesso frettoloso, una visione d'insieme della città attraverso l'evoluzione del suo patrimonio monumentale ed artistico.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=itinerario%20turistico%2Cpercorso%20turistico&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Citinerario%20turistico%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpercorso%20turistico%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: Grazie, Josh61.

Answer (score 2):

On the maps you will find "percorso turistico" or "itinerario turistico".
In your meaning, sometimes the word "strada" is used, but in connection with "panoramica" and not "turistica":    "strada panoramica".   But this last one is more referred to the landscape that you can watch driving on that road (and this usually is what the tourists like :)   )

Comment: Grazie per la risposta, Luca.